# How do you exclude symlinks in a grep?

Tags: grep

I want to `grep -R` a directory but exclude symlinks how dow I do it?

Maybe something like `grep -R --no-symlinks` or something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Gnu grep [v2.11-8 and on](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/grep-commit/2012-03/msg00048.html) if invoked with `-r` [excludes symlinks](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#File-and-Directory-Selection) not specified on the command line  and includes them when invoked with `-R`.

Comment: To clarify a bit, `grep -r PATTERN *` will search symlinks in the current directory, but `grep -r PATTERN .` will not

Comment: @james-geldart that is your shell expanding `*` to the contents of the current directory.  By the same token, `echo *` will list symlinks.  It has nothing to do with `grep`.  As stated `-r` excludes symlinks _not specified on the command line_.

Answer (score 19):

If you already know the name(s) of the symlinks you want to exclude:

```
grep -r --exclude-dir=LINK1 --exclude-dir=LINK2 PATTERN .
```

If the name(s) of the symlinks vary, maybe exclude symlinks with a find command first, and then grep the files that this outputs:

```
find . -type f -a -exec grep -H PATTERN '{}' \;
```

The '-H' to grep adds the filename to the output (which is the default if grep is searching recursively, but is not here, where grep is being handed individual file names.)

I commonly want to modify grep to exclude source control directories. That is most efficiently done by the initial find command:

```
find . -name .git -prune -o -type f -a -exec grep -H PATTERN '{}' \;
```

Comment: An alternative would be `grep PATTERN $(find -type f)`. Which is more readibly, and probably slower.

Comment: Why not `find . -type f -a -exec grep 'search' {} +`? Adding the `+` tells `find` to run `grep` with as many filenames as will fit on one command line, and this triggers it to put the filename on each line already, and is more efficient besides.

Comment: @ErikE That is an excellent suggestion, thanks. Now I come to re-read my answer to this question though, I notice that `man grep` says symlinks are not followed by default, so I'm puzzled why this question even exists in the first place. Did this behavior of grep change in the last few years?

Comment: ...ah, I see the top answer on this page now says exactly that.

Comment: ...and I even previously upvoted that answer. Oh dear.

Comment: That's nothing! I once went to upvote this really well-written answer that helped me on a serious problem I was stumped on, but it wouldn't let me upvote it, because it was my own answer I'd written two years before.

Answer (score 5):

For now.. here is how I would **exclude symbolic links when using grep**

---

**If you want just file names matching your search:**

```
for f in $(grep -Rl 'search' *); do if [ ! -h "$f" ]; then echo "$f"; fi; done;
```

Explaination:

- `grep -R             # recursive`
- `grep -l             # file names only`
- `if [ ! -h "file" ]  # bash if not a symbolic link`

---

**If you want the matched content output, how about a double grep:**

```
srch="whatever"; for f in $(grep -Rl "$srch" *); do if [ ! -h "$f" ]; then
  echo -e "\n## $f";
  grep -n "$srch" "$f";
fi; done;
```

Explaination:

- `echo -e             # enable interpretation of backslash escapes`
- `grep -n             # adds line numbers to output`

---

.. It's not perfect of course. But it could get the job done!

Answer (score 4):

If you're using an older grep that does not have the -r behavior described in Aryeh Leib Taurog's answer, you can use a combination of `find`, `xargs` and `grep`:

```
find . -type f | xargs grep "text-to-search-for"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using BSD grep (Mac) the following works similar to '-r' option of Gnu grep.

```
grep -OR <PATTERN> <PATH> 2> /dev/null
```

From man page

> -O      If -R is specified, follow symbolic links only if they were explicitly listed on the command line.